# Retrieve border color of WinForms ListBox/ListView rendered with OS visual styles

Tags: winforms, listview, listbox, border, visual-styles

If we create a new WinForms .NET project and place a ListBox or ListView control on it, by default they are rendered using the OS visual styles:

[image]

I need to draw a 1-pixel border similar to what the system provides for ListBox/ListView in my custom control. Is there a way to retrieve the color of that system border for ListBox/ListView using a system call?

Comment: Do you have an example image showing what you need? I personally use GroupBoxes in which other controls (like ListBox) are put. By changing the Padding and Margin you can set them to be very close to ListBox border, but again, I don't really know if that is what you're after.

Comment: See the [VisualStyleRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer) class. There are default rendering styles for some specific Controls, so you should probably specify what kind of Control you're building. -- Note that can just override CreateParams and add to the styles `WS_BORDER`, or `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` to the ExStyle (the Fixed3D version), if you just need your Control to show the default single or 3D borders.

Comment: @Jimi, The correct question should be how to draw the ListView border 'as is' because in the general case this border can be a gradient or whatever we can think of (and even thicker than 1 pixel line). But I need to draw the 1-pixel bounding rectangle for custom contents inside. I guess what I need is `VisualStyleRenderer.GetColor`.

Comment: Hmm, that won't probably adapt the Color to the background. When you add a Control to a Parent container, the border is rendered based on a calculation that considers the brightness of the Parent's background, so it's not always the same. Try this, in the `OnPaint()` override of a Custom Control: `var renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Button.PushButton.Normal); var edges = Edges.Left | Edges.Top | Edges.Right | Edges.Bottom; renderer.DrawEdge(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50), edges, EdgeStyle.Raised, EdgeEffects.Mono);`. Then change the background Color...

Comment: @Jimi, First, look at my screenshot. It's a classical WinForms app with TextBox, ListBox, ListView. Even if you change the form's BackColor to say LimeGreen, the border color of those 3 controls remain the same. Second, I found the theme TMT_BORDERCOLOR color property (ID is 3801) for ListBox and ListView. It returns the correct value I need. So, is it still a bad idea to retrieve the TMT_BORDERCOLOR theme property and draw the border with this color?

Comment: I'm not sure what you need. Just a Color? Which Color? There isn't just one single Color, the Theme decides the context in which the visual style is applied. Anyway, to simulate, e.g., a ListBox, you could render the default parts and state: `var rend = new VisualStyleRenderer("ListBox", 0, 0); rend.DrawBackground([DevContext], [Bounds], [Clip Bounds]);` and the fixed-single border as: `var rend = new VisualStyleRenderer("ListBox", 3, 1); rend.DrawBackground([DevContext], [Bounds], [Clip Bounds]);`. The `[DevContext]` param is `e.Graphics`, then specify the bounds to apply the rendering.

Comment: See also: [DrawThemeBackground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-drawthemebackground), [DrawThemeEdge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-drawthemeedge) and [Parts and States](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/parts-and-states) -- VisualStyleRenderer is (partial) wrapper  of the UxTheme functions.

Comment: @Jimi, I am trying to make my custom-made control look consistent with other similar list controls like ListBox or ListView. Currently the border is set by specifying the `WS_BORDER` window style. This gives RGB(64, 64, 64), which looks a little bit darker compared to the borders of ListBox and ListView - RGB(130, 135, 144) in Windows 10/11. I am starting to think that drawing my border using the border color of ListBox/ListView or even using `DrawThemeEdge` for ListBox/ListView may be not a very good idea. Perhaps, what the OS provides for `WS_BORDER` is the best solution. Your thought?

Comment: Well, setting `WS_BORDER` in CreateParams wil give you the ListBox / ListView border if you set the class name to either of these, otherwise not that border. But, try the two 
`VisualStyleRenderer.DrawBackground()` methods (which wrap UxTheme's  `DrawThemeBackground()`: the Border is non-client area) with the Class name, Parts and State IDs shown above (`0,0` being the default 3D Border and `3,1` the Fixed-Single variant).

Comment: BTW, the VisualStyles class name of the ListView Control is `LISTVIEW`, not `SysListView32` as one may think (i.e., not the same class name you specify in CreateParams to generate a ListView Control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick answer for C#/WinForms:

```
var rend = new VisualStyleRenderer("ListBox", 0, 0);
Color borderColor = rend.GetColor(ColorProperty.BorderColor);
```

You can also retrieve the same value with Windows API using the [GetThemeColor}(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-getthemecolor) function with the property identifier 3801:

[image]

However, in the general case the border may consist of different color values and/or be blended with the parent's background, so that the retrieved color value may be not exactly what you expect.